# Can we create a temporary table in java Or join a map with a table in java?

Tags: java, sql, join, querydsl

I need to sort the data that is retrieved from a table based on a map of data. The table contains a primary key (client ID). The map contains the primary key (client ID) with a set of values (years) associated to this primary key. I need to sort the data that is being retrieved based on this value (years) in map. And I'm using queryDSL.

Is it possible to join the map with the table OR is there any alternative solution?

Comment: what's the problem here ? You can sort directly map data as you said you are getting data in map through table

Comment: It would be best if you show some example of what your dataset looks like.

Comment: Are you looking for something like, sort map based on values rather than keys ?

Comment: I have a map which contains some data and I have a table which contains the other set of data. Now I have to retrieve the sorted contents of the table and the contents of the map together